# Select forum thread and latest reply

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a php/mysql forum, and it has two tables. The first is the master 'thread' table, and the second is the replies table, structures as such (omitting some columns that are not relevant to this question, such as 'title', 'body_text', etc).

1. thread_table
   Columns:

   - id (int, primary key)
   - user_id (int)
   - deleted (bool/tiny_int)
   - date_posted (datetime)
2. reply_table
   Columns:

   - id (int, primary key)
   - linked_to (int)
   - user_id (int)
   - deleted (bool/tiny_int)
   - date_posted (datetime)

I'm really stuck with my sql, I want to select all the 'threads', the latest 'reply' per thread where deleted does not equal 1, and also the total count of replies for each thread where deleted does not equal 1. And to top it off I also want to select the 'user_name' from my users table where the thread/reply 'user_id' is equal to the same id in the user table.

Comment: Do you want to use 1 query for this (because that will be messy, if not impossible)? Probably better to tackle this in small pieces.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, it's not a requirement to use one big messy query, I'm happy to break it into two and loop through the first result or whatever it takes!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use auto_increment on your id's so that the highest number is always the last reply.

Please note that the code below is **not tested** but it should help you along the way!
I've commented the steps so you can see what's happening where. Hope this helps you!

```
//Fetch the thread headers and put result in array
$get_header = "SELECT thread.id, user.user_name, thread.date_posted FROM thread_table thread, user_table user WHERE thread.user_id = user.user_id AND thread.deleted != 1;";
    $Rget_header = mysql_query($get_header) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row_get_header = mysql_fetch_array($Rget_header)){
            $arr_get_header[] = array( "thread_id"   => $row_get_header['id'],
                                       "username"    => $row_get_header['user_name'],
                                       "date_posted" => $row_get_header['date_posted']
                                      );
    }

//Loop through the header array 
for ($c = 0; $c < count($arr_get_header); $c++){

    //Fetch the count
    $count_replies = "SELECT COUNT(id) as reply_count FROM reply_table WHERE linked_to = '".$arr_get_header[$c]['thread_id']."';";
        $Rcount_replies = mysql_query($count_replies) or die(mysql_error());

        $num_count_replies = mysql_num_rows($Rcount_replies);

            if ($num_count_replies == 1) {
                $obj_get_reply = mysql_fetch_object($Rcount_replies);
            }

    //Get last reply
    $get_reply = "SELECT MAX(reply.id) as reply_id, user.user_name, reply.date_posted FROM reply_table reply, user_table user WHERE reply.user_id = user.id AND reply.deleted != 1 AND reply.linked_to = '".$arr_get_header[$c]['thread_id']."' ORDER BY reply_id;";
        $Rget_reply = mysql_query($get_reply) or die(mysql_error());

        $num_get_reply = mysql_num_rows($Rget_reply);

            if ($num_get_reply == 1) {
                $obj_get_reply = mysql_fetch_object($Rget_reply);
            }

    //Echo result
    echo 'Thread id: '.$arr_get_header[$c]['thread_id'].'<br />';
    echo 'Last reply id: '.$obj_get_reply->reply_id.'<br />';
    echo 'Reply count: '.$obj_count_replies->reply_count.'<br />';

}
```

Comment: hey that's great! thanks a lot for that, I'll have a play with it tomorrow (getting late here)

Comment: Any luck? Did this solve your problem? if so, please accept it as the answer :)